# hamachi broke my network interface or router

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, firmware

I would like to ask if somebody has a solution to my problem. This was done with Debian 10 server and the hamachi terminal version. So I have a set of servers one on my lan (Debian 10) and the other one on another network (Fedora).

I needed a VPN solution, I tried tinc for first but I had some install problems and config problems. I then chose hamachi as the solution, installed it the normal way, downloaded the .deb package, and used dpkg to install it.

But I didn't get that it will cut my ssh session off. With this fact, I connected my main machine (Kali Linux) which I use to control the servers, but ssh doesn't work in this ssh, it just cuts it off. A quick google search showed that there is some extension to hamachi that allows ssh to go through. So my friend had to go disconnect the machine from the virtual network, and that worked perfectly fine.

On my Debian server, I stopped the VPN with `sudo hamachi go-offline NetworkName` and that worked. But afterward, the Debian machine behaved like it is still on the VPN. I couldn't install packages, I couldn't use `apt-get update`, I couldn't ssh to it from the lan or from the internet like I used to. So the next step was to kill the hamachi process and the hamachi daemon.

But that didn't work. When I used `hostname -I`, I got a really weird IP, and I had still assigned an IPV6 address. I even determined that I have a still open port 22 with `nc -z -nv 127.0.0.1 20-80`  and the ssh process was active. I couldn't figure how to fix that so the next logical step was to reinstall it.

When I started it went smooth but it failed to automatically set up DHCP so I did it manually, but when I got to package manager I couldn't connect to any mirror, so with new knowledge I started googling again and found this [reddit thread about my problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/jv1sb/uninstalling_hamachi_breaks_all_networking_and/), so I am wondering if I broke my NIC or router and if somebody knows any solution. I tried everything and don't know what to do now. Maybe some firmware problem? Or iptable problem?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but I suspect your default route is via the VPN

Comment: well it was through the VPN but I can't even reinstall it, it shows up as an interface but can't connect to the network, it still behaves as it is on the VPN. Or what would like you to know? i am quite new at linux

Answer (score 0):

I figured it myself. I did some extensive troubleshooting, even tried a PCI network card, and I tried my other switch and it was working! Turns out that restart of my switch worked! It was just weird because it is a non-managable switch.